# Accurately representing long selectors' specificity with a single number

Tags: css, css-specificity

After reading through [this article](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) on CSS specificity it's clear that it's possible to represent the specificity of a selector with either a single number, for example `0110`, or a comma-separated set of numbers, for example `0,1,1,0`.

Let's say there is an extremely long and unnecessarily complicated selector that targets 12 classnames. The comma-separated value would be `0,0,12,0`. What would the number value be?